# How to give file path in backstretch using .net

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In my login page there are some images which should be played on background. My images is stored in my wwwroot folder as static files. But there is a path wrong when page loaded. My controller can't load images.

```
$.backstretch([
                "lib/assets/img/backgrounds/banner-1.jpg"
              , "lib/assets/img/backgrounds/banner-2.jpg"
              , "lib/assets/img/backgrounds/banner-3.jpg"
], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```

lib is folder wherein my wwwroot. When i looked at chrome console images path [as following this link](http://localhost:3577/account/lib/assets/img/backgrounds/banner-1.jpg).

How can i fix it without carrying images to account folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `lib` directory is under your `wwwroot` directory, so you need to add a leading `/` to the beginning of each path to make it an absolute path under `wwwroot`:

```
$.backstretch([
                "/lib/assets/img/backgrounds/banner-1.jpg"
              , "/lib/assets/img/backgrounds/banner-2.jpg"
              , "/lib/assets/img/backgrounds/banner-3.jpg"
], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```